# Postman-Run a folder issue

Tags: postman

Im using latest version of Postman v5.3.2
When running a **folder** with several requests inside of it, it is not executing them sequentially in the same order they appear in the main app. unlike when running the all collection that contains that folder.
Is this a bug or Postman do not support this?

Answer (score 1):

When you need to run anything sequentially through the Collection Runner, you need to add logic to the "Tests" tab in your request.

There is a built-in method call "setNextRequest" that you can use in this situation. (documentation: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/building_workflows) It's important to note that "setNextRequest" only runs when you use the Collection Runner. (not sure if this is a bug, or as intended)

Here is an example I made: https://www.getpostman.com/collections/78ffebd7823f47b26a21

In this example collection, you can see that ***Test*** checks for status 200, then if true, calls ***Test3*** using *setNextRequest* on line 3. The same is done inside of ***Test3*** on line 3, but we call ***Test2*** instead. In ***Test2*** we again run a test, but this time we're STOPPING the execution by supplying *null* to the method.

Note: you **MUST** to supply *null* as an argument to *setNextRequest* in ***Test2*** to prevent the collection from running over and over.

The results in the Collection Runner should look like this:[image]

Hope this helps someone.